# Align an object with the same-shaped points in 3D space

Tags: vectors, 3d, transition-matrix

**I have an object (a hexagon, an irregular one, so angles between the sides may vary)**, it is aligned straignt on the (0, 0, 0) coordinates, i know its coordinates and its points coordinates.

**And I have 6 points in space**, that if connected, represent exactly the same shape as my hexagon. I have their coordinates.

**Now how do I apply a new position and rotation to my hexagon in a way that it aligns perfectly to these points?** I know, that I proably can just translate each point of that hexagon to the new points, but that is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: Do you know which points correspond to which between your original hexagon and the transformed hexagon? Or is that something you also need to figure out?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yeah, the problem is, the order of points may not be the same.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the order of points may not be the same". You claim the tranformed hexagon is the same shape as the original. That shape requires a specific order of the vertices. If all you know are the 12 points (6 original, 6 transformed), then it just takes a little additional investigation to figure which points map to which.

Comment: Yes, I ment that I don't know which points map to which.